# awk syntax error a[$1]

Tags: awk, syntax-error

I have the following awk command:

```
awk -F $'\t' 
'BEGIN 
{ OFS = FS } 
{ if($1 % 5 == 0) {a[$1][$2][$3]+=$4; } } 
END 
{for (i in a) for (j in a[i]) for (k in a[i][j]) print i, j, k, a[i][j][k]}'
```

And an input file containing a list of 4 tuple id's:

```
9374    2150    26  1
7477    1808    58  1
4972    787 28  1
5617    8342    15  1
```

etc..

When I run the command on the input file I get the error:

> awk: syntax error at source line 1  context is    BEGIN { OFS = FS } {
>   if($1 % 5 == 0) >>>  {a[$1][ <<<  awk: illegal statement at source
>   line 1 awk: illegal statement at source line

I am not sure what the command is supposed to do, probably create an ID lookup file of some sort.

Answer (score 4):

You're using gawk-only syntax in a non-GNU awk. Get gawk or use `a[$1,$2,$3]` or similar instead of `a[$1][$2][$3]` and fix the rest of your code to match. Unfortunately not only didn't you provide any expected output but you didn't even provide input that **could** produce any output (none of your $1 values modded by 5 evaluate to 0) so this is obviously untested but it might be what you want:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}
($1 % 5) == 0 {
    a[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3] += $4
}
END {
    for (key in keys) {
        print key, a[key]
    }
}
```

Comment: For more details, you may have a look at gawk documentation on [multidimensional arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html#Multidimensional) and [arrays of arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html)

Comment: You could say `FS = OFS = SUBSEP = "\t"`, then `a[$1,$2,$3] += $4` -- I think that's more readable. That works with gawk, mawk and nawk

Comment: I agree that's a very reasonable approach but I feel like it might be getting a wee bit cryptic for newcomers like the OP so I think I'll leave it as-is and leave that as a comment, thanks. It'll work in any awk - they all support SUBSEP.